# Error de (Subindice fuera de intervalo) en Excel (Macros-Vda)

Tags: macros

Mi problema es el siguiente. Trato de hacer un botón con el cual:

1. Busque Archivo excel
2. Al seleccionarlo, copiar solo los campos con datos del rango A
3. Que se cierre el archivo
4. Que pegue los datos en el excel actual deode tengo el macro

Estamos usando esto pero me bota un error `(Subindice fuera de intervalo)` y no puedo soluccionarlo.

```
 'VBA Excel'
 Sub Prueba()

 Dim ss As Workbook
 Dim archivo As Workbook
 Dim nombreArchivo As Variant

 Set ss = ActiveWorkbook
 nombreArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.csv*")

 If nombreArchivo = False Then
     Exit Sub
 Else
     With Application
         .ScreenUpdating = False
         .EnableEvents = False
     End With
 End If

 Set archivo = Workbooks.Open(nombreArchivo)

 Dim AA As String
 AA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:A" & AA).Copy: ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

 Application.GoTo ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")


  For Each celda In Range("A1:A" & AA)
       celda.Value = Replace(celda.Value, "|", ",")
    Next


 archivo.Close
 End Sub
```

---

Si me funcionó con esto pero cuando es archivo .csv sale el mismo error pero si es excel normal normal me coje (Subindice fuera de intervalo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero a la vez era cambiarla la "|" a "," esto si me funciona
tambie quisiera de cambiar el formato del csv que es general a texto ya que me bota con comas y solo sale bien con formato de texto

Comment: Por favor, intentemos añadir a las preguntas y respuestas signos gramaticales como acentos y comas, sobre todo. A veces es muy difícil decodificar lo que se está leyendo. ***Yo calculo que el calculo que calculo el arbitro que arbitro, desanimo al prospero medico que prospero siendo critico con quien critico a quien le medico por un palpito tras un resbalon por un liquido. Y el domine, sin su habito, rotulo en publico el modulo en el que habito.***

Comment: Por favor, explica mejor esta parte: ***Si me funcionó con esto pero cuando es archivo .csv sale el mismo error pero si es excel normal normal me coje (Subindice fuera de intervalo)***

Answer (score 1):

Sin probarlo, creo que el error que recibes es porque cierras el Libro que contiene los datos a copiar antes de cambiarte al libro origen.

Te dejo un código que debería funcionar:

```
Sub Prueba()

Dim ss As Workbook
Dim archivo As Workbook
Dim nombreArchivo As Variant

Set ss = ActiveWorkbook
nombreArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

If nombreArchivo = False Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
End If

Set archivo = Workbooks.Open(nombreArchivo)

Dim AA As String
AA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

archivo.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:A" & AA).Copy: ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.GoTo ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")
archivo.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: sucede con solo csv si copio los datos a un libro de excel normal si funciona

Comment: Edite la publicacion gracias

Comment: @danny puedes aclararmelo un poco más? Exportas los datos a csv o guardas el workbook como csv? Como lo abres?, cuando te da el error, cuando esta en formato csv o xlsm?

Comment: el excel viene en csv y con el macro tengo que importar la informacion y remplazar '|' a ',' y luego exportarlo sin el macro solo la informacion a un excel normal

Comment: @DevGodeG con lo que me pasaste si me funciono ,pero cuando es csv me sale erro(Subindice fuera de intervalo)

Answer (score 1):

El error `Subíndice fuera de intervalo` se produce por un error de direccionamiento cuando intentamos acceder, con un índice, a un objeto que no existe. Este error se puede dar en cualquier línea de código que tenga intención de acceder a una hoja en particular y no sea encontrada. Puede ser porque el nombre o el número de hoja no coinciden. Si nos fijamos, en tu código llamas a todas las hojas **Hoja1** pero en el libro principal la hoja parece llamarse:

> **PadresHijos_Base_201712051632**

En este código se han sustituido los nombres de las hojas **"Hoja1"** por un **1**. Deberemos modificar nuestro código para que se adapte a nuestro libro.

Se ha modificado la parte final que detecta si hay o no carácter de separación y actúa en consecuencia. Por supuesto se aceptan ficheros ***.scv*** y ***.xlsm***

El fichero abierto para obtener los datos puede ser cerrado una vez hayamos copiado los datos sin necesidad de forzar el cambio de libro con

```
Application.GoTo ss.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1")
```

Todos estos cambios crean un código más legible y mejoran el rendimiento como por ejemplo eliminar **ELSE** tras la línea

```
If nombreArchivo = False Then Exit Sub
```

Lógicamente, si *nombreArchivo* no es falso (existe) todo el código posterior al ***if*** será ejecutado por lo que utilizar un ***else*** no es necesario.

```
'Vba'
'Ejemplo con carácter de separación ";"'
Sub Prueba()

Dim ss As Workbook
Dim archivo As Workbook
Dim nombreArchivo As Variant
Dim AA As String
Dim pos As Integer

    Set ss = ActiveWorkbook
    nombreArchivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.csv*")

    'No hace falta ELSE'
    If nombreArchivo = False Then Exit Sub

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set archivo = Workbooks.Open(nombreArchivo)
    AA = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    archivo.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & AA).Copy: ss.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    archivo.Close
    For Each celda In ss.Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & AA)
        'Aquí pones el simbolo separador, en tu caso "|"'
        v_pos = InStr(1, celda, ";") - 1
        'Esta línea detecta si hay carácter de separación o no'
        If v_pos < 1 Then v_pos = Len(celda)
        celda.Value = Left(celda, v_pos)
    Next
End Sub
```

Resultado al correr este código sobre ficheros **.scv** y **.xlsm**
[image: Resultado del código]